# Parallel requests with coroutines

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to fetch some data from multiple locations to fill a recyclerView. I used to use callbacks, which worked fine, but need to refactor it to coroutines.

So i have a list of retrofit services and call each on of them parallerl. Then i can update the recyclerView with the onResponse callback. How can i achive this with coroutines.

I tried something like that, but the next call is fired after i got a response:

```
runblocking {
    for (service in services) {
        val response = async(Dispatchers.IO) {
            service.getResponseAsync()
        }
        adapter.updateRecyclerView(response.await())
    }
}
```

With another approach i had the problem that i was not able to get back on the main thread to update my ui as i was using launch and could not await the response:

```
runblocking {
    services.foreach {
        launch(Dispatcher.IO) {
            val response = it.getResponseAsync()
        }
        withContext(Dispatcher.Main) {
            adapter.updateRecyclerView(response)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm thankfull for every tip ;)
cheers patrick

Comment: `runBlocking` should never be used outside tests. It completely defeats the purpose of using coroutines. Out of curiosity, why did you choose to use it? I see it in questions on here day after day, so people must be getting the idea from somewhere.

Comment: They likely get it from the official documentation... pages like this:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html#scope-builder-and-concurrency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `await()` call suspends the current coroutine and frees the current thread for being attached by other queued coroutines.

So when `await()` is called the current coroutine suspends till the response is received, and that's why for loop does not complete (goes to next iteration before completion of before request).

---

First and foremost you should not be using the `runBlocking` here, it is highly discouraged to be used in production evironment.

You should instead be using the ViewModel scope provided by android for structured concurrency (cancels the request if no longer needed like if lifecycle of activity is over).

You can use view model scope like this in activity or fragment `viewModelOwner.viewModelScope.launch(/*Other dispatcher if needed*/) {}` or make a coroutine scope yourself with a job attached which cancels itself on onDestroy.

---

For the problem the coroutine does not do parallel requests, you can launch multiple request without await (ing) on them inside the for loop.

And select them, using select expression https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/select-expression.html#selecting-deferred-values

Example:

```kotlin
viewModelOwner.viewModelScope.launch {
    val responses = mutableListOf<Deferred<TypeReturnedFromGetResponse>>()
    for (service in services) {
        async(Dispatchers.IO) {
            service.getResponseAsync()
        }.let(responses::add)
    }

    // adds which ever request is done first in oppose to awaiting for all then update
    for (i in responses.indices) {
        select<Unit> {
            for (response in responses) {
                response.onAwait {
                    adapter.updateRecyclerView(it)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**PS: Using this method looks ugly but will update the adapter as soon as whichever request is first resolved, instead of awaiting for each and every request and then updating the items in it.**

Comment: Yes, it was totally clear that the loop didn't complete before the completion of the request. The problem was that i didn't know how to break this in the "coroutine" way. Your solution is what i was looking for and works perfect. I have read the docs you linked before, but would never come up with this solution :D :D
So thank you very much. i really appreciate it

Answer (score 7):

Start coroutines with `launch` instead of `runBlocking`. The examples below assume you're launching from a context that uses `Dispatchers.Main` by default. If that's not the case, you could use `launch(Dispatchers.Main)` for these.

If you want to update your view every time any of the parallel actions returns, then move your UI update inside the coroutines that you're launching for each of the `service` items:

```
for (service in services) {
    launch {
        val response = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { service.getResponseAsync() }
        adapter.updateRecyclerView(response)
    }
}
```

If you only need to update once all of them have returned, you can use `awaitAll`. Here, your `updateRecyclerView` function would have to be written to handle a list of responses instead of one at a time.

```
launch {
    val responses = services.map { service ->
        async(Dispatchers.IO) { service.getResponseAsync() }
    }
    adapter.updateRecyclerView(responses.awaitAll())
}
```

Comment: Indeed. This is a common scenario handled roughly the same way regardless of the asynchronous primitives in use (i.e. Promises, Tasks, Coroutines) or the programming language (i.e. JavaScript, Kotlin, C#)
 awaiting in the loop is an easy mistake to make when one is starting out. Anyway, nice answer.